# rails inverse of a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope

Is there a method to negate the result of a scope?
I have 3 models, associated by has_many :through association

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_training_maps
    has_many :trainings, through: :user_training_maps
end
```

training.rb

```
class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_training_maps
    has_many :users, through: :user_training_maps
end
```

user_training_map.rb

```
class UserTrainingMap < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :training
end
```

Before, I want to find all users belonging (enrolled) to a training. In user.rb, this works:

`scope :all_enrolled, -> { joins(:trainings) }`

Now, I need help to find all users NOT belonging (unenrolled) to a training. I can't get this to work:
`scope :all_unenrolled, -> { !joins(:trainings) }`
instead, it simply returns all the users. Something like `unenrolled users = (all users) - (enrolled users)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

`scope : all_enrolled, -> { joins(:trainings) }
scope :not_enrolled, -> { where.not(id: all_enrolled) }`

Comment: Semantically I agree that this example is better, but the `explain` suggests that the query is more complex with two `where` clauses. So YMMV with query speeds if that's important to you.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord has `left_joins` for a while now, so you should be able to do it directly in the same way you'd do it if you were to write plain SQL:

```rb
  scope :not_enrolled, { left_joins(:trainings).where(trainings: {id: nil}) }
```